# ModuleNotFoundError in Python 3.8.3

Tags: python-3.x, exception, module

I've a problem with the importations of modules in Python. I'm doing a project with PyQt and I'm trying to refactor and restructure it.

The hierarchy is the next:

```
./main.py
./logic/__init__.py
./logic/transforms.py
./logic/hopfield.py
./gui/__init__.py
./gui/interface.py
./gui/mplwidget.py
./img
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gui.interface import Ui_MainWindow
  File ...\gui\interface.py", line 215, in <module>
    from mplwidget import MplWidget
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mplwidget'
```

The file interface.py

```py
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
  .
  .
  .

from mplwidget import MplWidget
```

The file main.py

```py
import sys
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

from gui.interface import Ui_MainWindow
from gui.weightMatrix import Ui_Dialog
from gui.table import TableModel

from logic.hopfield import learn, searchPattern
from logic.transforms import transformVector, transformVectors

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Actions(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
         .
         .
         .
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work, since inside the module if I run the interface file it works fine together with `mplwidget` as a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File ...\gui\interface.py", line 215, in
>
> from mplwidget import MplWidget

your `interface.py` should have

absolute import:
`from gui.mplwidget import MplWidget`

or

relative import:
`from .mplwidget import MplWidget`

In addition, a great [blog](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) that explains the two different imports

Comment: That is the solution. It's simpler than I thought.  Thanks for the information and quick response!